# R plotting multiple survival curves in the same plot

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I am trying to plot multiple survival curves in the same plot. Using `plot` I can easily do this by

```
plot(sr_fit_0, col = 'red' , conf.int=TRUE, xlim=c(0, max_m))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(sr_fit_1,  col ='blue', conf.int=TRUE, xlim=c(0, max_m))`
```

But now I want to use `ggsurv` to plot survival curve and I don't know how to have both of them in the same plot(not subplots). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 8):

I generated some data for life below for life of hamsters and gerbils.  You can use the survfit() function similar to other curve fitting functions and define a data frame column that splits the population.  When you create the plot with ggsurv() I think it will display what you are looking for.

```
## Make some data for varmint life
set.seed(1); l1 <- rnorm(120, 2.5, 1)
gerbils <- data.frame(life = l1[l1>0])
set.seed(3); l2 <- rnorm(120, 3, 1)
hamsters <- data.frame(life = l2[l2>0])

## Load required packages
require('survival'); require('GGally')

## Generate fits for survival curves
## (Note that Surv(x) creates a Survival Object)
sf.gerbils <- survfit(Surv(life) ~ 1, data = gerbils)
sf.hamsters <- survfit(Surv(life) ~ 1, data = hamsters)
ggsurv(sf.gerbils) #Survival plot for gerbils
ggsurv(sf.hamsters) #Survival plot for hamsters

## Combine gerbils and hamsters while adding column for identification
varmints <- rbind((cbind(gerbils, type = 'gerbil')),
                  (cbind(hamsters, type = 'hamster')))

## Generate survival for fit for all varmints as a function of type
sf.varmints <- survfit(Surv(life) ~ type, data = varmints)

## Plot the survival curves on one chart
ggsurv(sf.varmints)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't show the confidence intervals anymore.

Comment: You should try '?survfit' at the R console prompt or look at the GGally package reference on CRAN.  There is a CI parameter that can be set to true to plot confidence intervals. (I did not test it).

Comment: Thanks a lot it's actually ggsurv(sf.varmints, CI=TRUE)